# git push not working?

Tags: git, github, push

everytime i try to push , its telling me that i cant push to git://github.com/somegitrepo.git

it tells me to use https://github.com/somegitrepo.git , and it will work only if i type git push https://github.com/somegitrepo.git everytime  i push

my remote -v shows my origins for push and fetch as

git://github.com/somegitrepo.git

How do i go about fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive when you try to push?

Comment: You have your remote alias set up to use SSH. Did you set up your SSH keys with GitHub? Is your private key encrypted with a passphrase? Are you using `ssh-agent` to decrypt it? Are you using Windows, OS X, or Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/somegitrepo.git"` will change address of origin.

Problem with using `git://` version may be caused by badly configured (or just lacking) SSH keys.

Answer (score 1):

1. delete any existing ssh key (/.ssh/id_rsa).
2. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" #generation of new ssh key
   Email github wali.
3. after ssh key generation.
4. eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   To start ssh agent
5. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
6. clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
7. paste this into the ssh key section of github.

Now pushing git

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m ""
4. git status
   To check for the files.
5. git remote add origin "url of the repo"
   This step only for the first time.
6. git push -u origin master
   This is used for the initial push.
   Otherwise use
   git push.

**If still not working----**
***go to credential manager then windows credential and delete personel access token of github.***